# GLSL, Fragment Shader: How to separate functions (like noise, transform...) to reuse in different projects

Tags: shader, glsl, pixel-shader, function

I'm a total newbie to coding and recently got interested into generative art.
This is my problem:
I have to copy all of the functions I need (and there are a lot) in every single fragment file I'm working on.
I'm wondering if there is a way to keep all the functions in a separate file(s) and import what I need, into the fragment file I'm working on.
Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the framework/app, some GLSL implementations may support using `#include` to bring in code from another file. Can you tell us more about where/how you're using GLSL? Are you coding your own app, or using it within some engine, sandbox, etc.?